# Selenium Click button whitout id

Tags: python, selenium

i have to **click the input type="button"** element of the first li, but i **can not** refer to the id of the li, since it changes every time i i open the website, this is what i tried

```py
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//input[data-componentname="gender"]').get(0).click()
```

and it gives me this error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'
```

if i remove the get part, this is the error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'
```

This is the code, like i said, i have to click the first input without referring to the id

```py
<ul data-componentname="gender">
    
      <li id="78ece221-1b64-4124-8483-80168f21805f" class="">
        <input type="button">
        <span>Uomo</span>
      </li>
    
      <li id="2678a655-b610-41e0-8e7f-bad58fbcb1b3" class="">
        <input type="button">
        <span>Donna</span>
      </li>
    
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click on the element <kbd>Uomo</kbd> you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54193625/how-to-click-on-a-element-through-selenium-python/54194511#54194511) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul[data-componentname='gender'] li:nth-of-type(1) span"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@data-componentname='gender']//span[text()='Uomo']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Browser Snapshot:

[image: Ummo]

Answer (score 0):

`find_elements` method return a list of web elements.
The first member of the list can be received by simple indexation i.e. `list_object[0]`
Also, since you want to get the first element matching the `//input[data-componentname="gender"]` locator you can simply use `find_element` method.
So, instead of

```py
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//input[data-componentname="gender"]').get(0).click()
```

You can use

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[data-componentname="gender"]').click()
```

Or

```py
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//input[data-componentname="gender"]')[0].click()
```

**UPD**
well, you tried to use a wrong locator.
This should work:

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@data-componentname='gender' ]//span[text()='Uomo']/../input").click()
```

You can also click the element containing the "Uomo" text itself as well

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@data-componentname='gender' ]//span[text()='Uomo']").click()
```

Comment: i get this errors 
for the first: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'
for the second: IndexError: list index out of range
i may need to click the input type button that's inside the list instead of the list..

Comment: That means the list is empty. Please share all your code including the link to the page you are working on or the HTML of the entire page.

Comment: https://www.nike.com/it/register this is the page, i need to click the button called Uomo the one below the country dropdown

Comment: See my updated answer and let me know if now it's OK

Answer (score 0):

You can include the first li if you only want that. For example:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[data-componentname="gender"]/li[1]')
```

otherwise if you want the list then you can do

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('input[data-componentname="gender"] > li')
```

and do the .get() according to which button you want to click

Comment: Can you indent your code please for better readability?